# Augmenting global in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, declaration-files

How can I add `fetch` onto the global object in TypeScript so I don't have to do this:

```
(global as any).fetch
```

I've tried this in a file in `./types/index.d.ts`

And tried to reference it by including it in the tsconfig.json.

Comment: We are talking about node `global` right ?

Comment: yes sir i am indeed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [Go to Definition](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_rich-languages-editing) on `global` you will see it [declared in node definition files](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/84e570d484092ec6ce430adb33b14ce353c9f924/types/node/globals.d.ts#L163) as :

```
declare var global: NodeJS.Global;
```

So in order to add things to it you just need to augment the `Global` interface in the `NodeJS` namespace:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
    export interface Global {
        fetch(u: string): string
    }
}
global.fetch("") // ok now
```

Comment: say I have this in an index.d.ts file.  Do I need to add this file to paths in tsconfig.json?

Comment: @dagda1 If it is not added to the compilation paths in any other way then yes you need to add it t tsconfig.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation